# App widget can not take focus in ICS (Android 4.0)?

Tags: android, widget, focus, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have exactly the same code that works on Froyo but not ICS.
Yet I still could see some default app widgets from ICS that can take focus from d-pad such as **bookmark** and **music playlist**.

I'm doing a project on ICS that would show a grid view which need to take focus and interacted with user by the D-pad.

Anyone has any thoughts on this?